# Use desired timezone in javascript 24 hour countdown or offset the countdown so it hits 00:00 at 11:00 local time instead of at 00:00 local time

Tags: javascript, loops, time, timer, clock

I have this 24 hour loop countdown and i need it to reset at 11:00 every day instead of at 00:00 like it does now, right now it uses local time zone so either have to change time zone that it uses or time by it by 11 hours.

And the next thig i need to do with it is to format it so when hours and minutes hit one digit values it will be formaten with zero before that nuber, so 05:02:55 instead of 5:2:55 like now.
Can some one help me? Thnaks

Heres the script:

pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWGRoa

```
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 23 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 10){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#the-final-countdown p').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Just as a comment: you can rewrite the `jQuery` statement as `document.querySelector('#the-final-countdown p').innerHTML=hours+':'+min+':'+sec;`. It may look slightly longer, but, by avoiding a jQuery call, it will save dozens of not hundreds of steps. jQuery is _very_ long-winded about interpreting a simple statement.

Comment: Also, you can zero-pad your minutes and seconds (why not hours?) this way: `min=('0'+min).slice(-2);` and `sec=('0'+sec).slice(-2);`. That will also fix a bug in your code which tests for a length of 10 for your minutes.

Comment: In the codepen, he has `length == 1` for both minutes and seconds, so I think it is just a typo in the question.

Comment: thanks that fixed the formating, now i only need to offset the time it hits 0, still no idea how

Comment: Not the most elegant, but you could do something like `if(d.getHours() <= 22){
    hours = 22 - d.getHours();
  }else{
    hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  }`. Haven't tested the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore user's time zone you need to work with the UTC version of `Date`. Remember that the time you set for rollover is then also UTC.

To get accurate day duration even during daylight saving time changes you should stick to date arithmetic.

```
function time() {
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = Date.UTC(d1.getUTCFullYear(),
                      d1.getUTCMonth(),
                      d1.getUTCDate() + (d1.getUTCHours() < 11 ? 0 : 1),
                      11);
    var dh = d2 - d1;
    var hours = Math.floor(dh / 3600000);
    var dm = dh - 3600000 * hours;
    var min = Math.floor(dm / 60000);
    var ds = dm - 60000 * min;
    var sec = Math.floor(ds / 1000);
    var dmilli = ds - 1000 * sec;
    setTimeout(time, dmilli);
    hours = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
    min = ('0' + min).slice(-2);
    sec = ('0' + sec).slice(-2);
    document.querySelector('#the-final-countdown p').innerHTML = hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
}
time();
```

`d2` is the `Date` the counter will rollover. Adapt accordingly.

As a bonus this repeatedly calls `setInterval()` so that the countdown ticks at the same time as the wall clock.